# Meaning of "dürfen müssen"

Tags: meaning, modal-verb

From [Focus](http://www.focus.de/sport/videos/airbags-inklusive-nackt-model-bietet-reus-seine-fahrdienste-an_id_4365376.html):

> Dank dieser Gerüchte dürfte Marco Reus zum ersten Mal in seiner Führerschein-Affäre schmunzeln müssen.

What does "dürfte ... schmunzeln müssen" mean? Is he allowed to smile, or must he smile, or what?

Comment: related:http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17883/the-other-uses-of-dürften-and-sollen-outside-allowed-to-and-shall-ought-to/17885#17885

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"dürfte" is Konjunktiv II of "dürfen" and means as much as "most likely" in this context. The whole sentence therefore means that "he most likely has to smile".

Answer (score 3):

"Dürfte etwas müssen" can be translated to "probably had to do something"

Answer (score 2):

The "Gerüchte" are so funny/crazy that the author of the sentence expects Marco Reus to smile despicte the bad "Führerschein-Affäre".

It's like "most likely we can expect Marco Reus to smile".